# About HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to calculate and draw magnitude of the complex number using highcharts. My code it is showing real and imaginary values separately in the graph. The "For loop" i used is not working. Please tell me where I did wrong? I am new to Highcharts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <script>

        function makeChart(){

            $('#container').highcharts({


                title: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: ''
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },

                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                series: [{
                    "name": "rawDataFreq",
                    "data": [0.005,
                        0.01,
                        0.015,
                        0.02,
                        0.024999999,
                        0.029999998,
                        0.035,
                        0.04,
                        0.045,
                        0.049999997,
                        0.054999995,
                        0.06,
                        0.065,
                        0.07,
                        0.075,
                        0.08,
                        0.085,
                        0.09,
                        0.095,
                        0.1,
                        0.105,
                        0.11,
                        0.115,
                        0.12,
                        0.125,
                        0.13,
                        0.13499999,
                        0.13999999,
                        0.145,
                        0.14999999,
                        0.15499999,
                        0.16,
                        0.16499999,
                        0.16999999,
                        0.175,
                        0.17999999,
                        0.18499999,
                        0.19,
                        0.195,
                        0.19999999,
                        0.20499998]
                }, {
                    "name": "rawDataReal",
                    "data": [0.0201808685573576,
                        0.0767697223756945,
                        0.158682648165923,
                        0.249837894338925,
                        0.332117497531074,
                        0.388486758487953,
                        0.405658247813341,
                        0.375893015564664,
                        0.297781091351485,
                        0.176066765803544,
                        0.0207198248638412,
                        -0.154486149201635,
                        -0.333632455792532,
                        -0.50034171901689,
                        -0.639326270705166,
                        -0.73769508266917,
                        -0.78595341067365,
                        -0.778665026494336,
                        -0.714772534308723,
                        -0.597587985327756,
                        -0.434481612563418,
                        -0.236305675925078,
                        -0.0166000654885318,
                        0.209367793245636,
                        0.425668306470451,
                        0.616818629518453,
                        0.768867682979019,
                        0.870392411592417,
                        0.913338195367741,
                        0.893650069853281,
                        0.811642807549262,
                        0.672076423910065,
                        0.483922946878543,
                        0.259820779969512,
                        0.015255193586922,
                        -0.23249535939003,
                        -0.465581710361413,
                        -0.666874686000139,
                        -0.821246389838196,
                        -0.91674068380029,
                        -0.94553784066234]
                }, {
                    "name": "rawDataImag",
                    "data": [0.0675545914177537,
                        0.117156377483156,
                        0.134184248961863,
                        0.109954668889497,
                        0.0430934390486774,
                        -0.0604922824628415,
                        -0.188868821726251,
                        -0.32615740460395,
                        -0.454964125730713,
                        -0.558727284498096,
                        -0.623674108742807,
                        -0.640215131053008,
                        -0.603726043334295,
                        -0.514749853472742,
                        -0.378702137106123,
                        -0.205185549905176,
                        -0.00702389181498738,
                        0.200878821925561,
                        0.402758663360984,
                        0.583207037132255,
                        0.728307795918874,
                        0.826634253007817,
                        0.870054851853836,
                        0.854307437716744,
                        0.779313360666507,
                        0.649215214597493,
                        0.472135336231634,
                        0.2596646296396,
                        0.0261122004577115,
                        -0.212445675964786,
                        -0.439266519954881,
                        -0.638109861272021,
                        -0.794408318676894,
                        -0.896357162635668,
                        -0.935831163700915,
                        -0.909067785047298,
                        -0.817049526245347,
                        -0.665548148633306,
                        -0.464818102478558,
                        -0.228945676059982,
                        0.0251035652398094]


                }]



            })

            var result = 0;
            var resultArray = new Array ();
            var x = 0;
            var y=0;
            for (i=0; i < rawDataFreq.length; i++)
            {
                result = 0;
                x=rawDataReal[i];
                y=rawDataImag[i];
                result = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2)));
                resultArray[i] = result;
            }

        }

        $(window).load(makeChart);


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`rawDataFreq` doesn't seem to exist in your `for` loop.
You should try to store the raw data in a variable, then reference it in `series.dataname` and in your `for` loop.

```
function makeChart(){
    var rawDataFreq = [/* your data array */];

    $('#container').highcharts({
        /* code truncated */
        series: [{
            "name": "rawDataFreq",
            "data": rawDataFreq
        }]
        /* code truncated */
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < rawDataFreq.length; i++) {
        /* code truncated */
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get series data with ```var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); rawDataFreq = chart.series[0].data``` after rendering the chart.